# How to code bulk order form in wordpress

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

We developing a website for wholesale marketer, In this when user click on products for eg. if user see t-shirt, he can choose multiple sizes, colors at a time and if user select 3 sizes for a product then in an increment box value show as 3

is this possible in wordpress without using paid plugin.

Comment: Isnt woocommerce an option? Or too big?

Answer (score -1):

Yes definitely.

You can create a form with data grid with option to add rows using javascript in realtime. 
Once the form is submitted you can import each row into **WP Post** table with post type **'products'**.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Do you have a reference website link for this? Please provide if you have.